# Is Chrome available on Windows Phone 8?

Tags: 8.0, browser

I have a Nokia Lumia 520 and really want to use Chrome. There seem to be a few knock-off versions of Chrome on the Windows Store.

Is there an official version?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Chrome is not yet available for Windows Phone. If you want to try an alternate browser, [Opera Mini](http://windowsphone.com/s?appId=b3bf000a-e004-4ecb-a8fb-9fc817cdab90) and [UC Browser](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-gb/store/app/uc-browser/6cda5651-56b9-48b0-8771-91dbc188f873) are available.

Comment: I use IE mostly and Opera Mini a little bit.  What I've been wondering, do Opera Mini and UC Browser use their own rendering engine (WebKit and ???) or are they more or less skins on the Trident engine?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest other browsers like Opera Mini and UC Browser, Maxthon or Surfy. They are some nice ones and one or the other will suit in some way. Give it a try.

Also, I found this article where the details have been written about other browsers: [Best Browsers for Windows Phone](http://www.windowsphonesearch.com/2015/12/best-browsers-for-windows-phone.html).